# Should I write test for each decorator or the using class will be enough?

Tags: unit-testing, decorator

Sorry if my question is not clear.
I implemented a decorator pattern in my application.
Inside of a class(for example DecoratorManager) in according to passed parameters different type of decorator will be created.
My question is that writing test for DecoratorManager class will be enough or should I also write test
for each decorator?
Because in my test I'm passing different parameters to DecoratorManager and check the result according to respective decorator.
I also checked code coverage and it shows 100 percent.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should be mocking the decorators and test them separately. You don't want DecoratorManager tests to fail because of a bug on any of the decorators implementation. If you keep it like this is not technically a unit test but a integration test.

Something else that I'd like to point out is about coverage: I think it is more important to test the correct things and well that test absolutely everything.